# Must Reenter PFX Password Every Time Developer Pulls Branch from TFS Workaround?

Tags: passwords, clickonce, pfx, strong-named-key

11 of the DLLs in my solution must use PFX certificates (very large enterprise application using Click-Once install). The certificates work perfectly, except every time someone pulls down a TFS branch from a different developer/workstation the certificate password is invalid and they receive:

*Error Cannot import the following key file: CertificateName.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_DB583A44F66CCF4B    AssemblyName*

Forcing them to **reenter the same password for all 11 assemblies** [image below]. What is a solution/fix for this very time consuming rigmarole?

[image]

*I do understand that entering the same password from a different workstation uses local values producing technically a different key, but I'm sure I'm not the first person to have this problem.*

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by blocking the .pfx files from being checked-in and brought down from TFS. Three potential solutions emerged:

1. **Forbidden Pattern Policy** using Server TFS Power Tools.

   stackoverflow.com/questions/2741412/forbidden-patterns-check-in-policy-in-tfs-2010

   msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
2. **TFS 'Cloaking'**

   stackoverflow.com/questions/29808807/how-to-cloak-directories-in-tfs-command-line

   [MSDN - Cloaking in TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fai/archive/2008/10/02/cloaking-in-tfs.aspx)
3. **.tfignore** *(the chosen solution)*

   [AIS Blog - excluding-files-from-team-foundation-version-control-using-tfignore-files](http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/11/06/excluding-files-from-team-foundation-version-control-using-tfignore-files/)

In the end, .tfignore I found to be the best solution. The .tfignore was automatically generated by Selecting the 'Detected changes link' in the Excluded section of Pending Changes Page, then choosing **Ignore by extension** (*.pfx) from the PFX file's shortcut menu.

The .tfignore was introduced to the root of the mapped workspace so this rule would be immediately applied to every developer's workspace on next pull from TFS.

```
    ################################################################################
# This .tfignore file was automatically created by Microsoft(R) Visual Studio.
#
# Local items matching filespecs in this file will not be added to version
# control. This file can be checked in to share exclusions with others.
#
# Wildcard characters are * and ?. Patterns are matched recursively unless the
# pattern is prefixed by the \ character.
#
# You can prepend a path to a pattern to make it more specific. If you do,
# wildcard characters are not permitted in the path portion.
#
# The # character at the beginning of a line indicates a comment.
#
# The ! prefix negates a pattern. This can be used to re-include an item after
# it was excluded by a .tfignore file higher in the tree, or by the Team
# Project Collection's global exclusions list.
#
# The / character is interpreted as a \ character on Windows platforms.
#
# Examples:
#
#  # Excludes all files ending in .txt in Alpha\Beta and all its subfolders.
#  Alpha\Beta\*.txt
#
#  # Excludes all files ending in .cpp in this folder only.
#  \*.cpp
#
#  # Excludes all files ending in .cpp in this folder and all subfolders.
#  *.cpp
#
#  # If "Contoso" is a folder, then Contoso and all its children are excluded.
#  # If it is a file, then only the "Contoso" in this folder is excluded.
#  \Contoso
#
#  # If Help.exe is excluded by a higher .tfignore file or by the Team Project
#  # Collection global exclusions list, then this pattern re-includes it in
#  # this folder only.
#  !\Help.exe    
#
################################################################################

*.pfx
```